# Show AlertDialog on screen if I switch from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I am facing issue with showing AlertDialog when I switch from one activity to another through navigation(Back button).

scenario is like this:
1. My application is running on and I am on second Page of application.
2. I press back button but at same time for second page one scenario is execute & AlertDialog is open on screen.
3. I already press back button I redirect to main screen & AlertDialog dismiss  with  out any user input.

Already used this ,but it should not work for me.

```
1.  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
2. onRetainNonconfigurationInstance() & getLastNonConfigurationInstance()
```

I want to show same AlertDialog on Home Page (MainActivity),if I navigate through it.
I want to do this for all my pages to home one.

Anybody having any kind of idea & suggestion.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you showing alert on caller activity? Show that on called activity. And share your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get user interaction before user leave 2nd Activity then You have to put AlertDialog in `onStop()` or`onDestroy()` of **2nd Activity** or If you want to show AlertDialog after your 2nd Activity is closed and You are in Main Activity then you have to put AlertDialog in `onActivityResult()` of **Main Activity**. (But for this you have to start 2nd Activity from MAin Activity using `startActivityForResult()`)

Answer (score 1):

Step1: Put your SharedPreferences inside your Second Activity

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences(
                                "myPrefs", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
prefsEditor.putString("ALERT","YES");
prefsEditor.commit();
```

Step2:

Inside OnCreate of your HomeActivity Write Below Code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     // Getting ALERT from Sharedpreference 
    myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 0);
    ALERT = myPrefs.getString("ALERT", "NO");
         if(ALERT.equals("YES"){
           // Write your Code for Showing Alert Dialogue
           }else{
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
            // Write rest og the Code for Your Home Acitivity
          }
```

Here you will have to setcontentview for HomeActivity after Finishing your AlertDialogue.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

and if you want to show alert dialog on your 2nd Activity itself,before launching MainActivity then use following concept,

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    showAlertDialog(SecondActivity.this);

}

    private void showAlertDialog(Context mCtx) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mCtx);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setTitle("Title");
    builder.setMessage("Message text !!");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });
    builder.create().show();        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        final Dialog CloseDialog = new Dialog(Sample.this);
        CloseDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        CloseDialog.setContentView(R.layout.exit_dialog_box);
        ExitButton = (Button) CloseDialog.findViewById(R.id.ExitButton);
        CloseExitDilog = (Button) CloseDialog
                .findViewById(R.id.CloseExitDialog);

        ExitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                     ....../////////

            }
        });

        CloseExitDilog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ///
            }
        });
        CloseDialog.show();
    }
```